# How to set joe to disable word wrap for *.R files?

Tags: joe

What do I put in .joerc to disable word wrap for *.R files?

Comment: Have a look into `$HOME/.joe/ftyperc` as that is the place where file type specific settings are usually done and search in there for `*.r` to see if below that there is any `-wordwrap` flag enabled.

Comment: thanks @cmur2! There actually was some stupid rule to do `-wordwrap` for all `*.*` files! Had to delete this. You can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default wordwrap is not enabled in JOE in general but depending on the settings in your local `$HOME/.joe/ftyperc` for `*.*` or `*.r` it could be enabled for specific file types. To resolve the problem look into your `ftyperc`.